# Pass list to the curl command in Shell

Tags: shell, github, github-api

How can I pass a list of assignees to the curl command?

```
assignees=("user1","user2")

issue_response=$(curl \
    -X POST \
    -u :"$GH_TOKEN" \
    -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
    "$GITHUB_API_ENDPOINT" \
    -d '{"title": "'"$issue_title"'", "body": "'"$issue_subject"'", "labels":["failure"], "assignees":["'"$assignees"'"]}')
echo "$issue_response"
```

When I trace this POST request I found the following issue, it is not a valid list.

```
"assignees":["user1,user2"]
```

Ideally, it should be

```
"assignees":["user1","user2"]
```

Can someone point me how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The array assignment `assignees=("user1","user2")` is creating an array but placing both user1 and user2 into the first place via string concatenation with the `,` character.

In order to insert both items into the array you should put a space between them.

`assignees=("user1" "user2")`

Then you can access each item via `${assignees[0]} and ${assignees[1]}`

To place the items dynamically into the curl command you have, you would have to build the string in a for loop like this:

```
assignees=("user1" "user2" "user3")
 for i in "${!assignees[@]}"
  do outputvar+="\"${assignees[$i]}\"" # Add assignee to variable
   if [ $i -lt $(expr ${#assignees[@]} - 1) ] # Add comma unless it's the last item
    then outputvar+=","
   fi done
echo $outputvar
```